# MySql for Excel: How to prevent changing MySql data when using MySql for Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-workbench

I am bit of a novice to MySql and have a relatively basic question regarding using MySql for Excel:

If I alter the data that I imported from mysql excel within the spreadsheets, will it change the original data within the tables in MySql?

I am currently planning on dumping large data sets from my job's MySql database into Excel to run some analyses but want to make sure it doesn't affect the data within MySql.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing whether Excel would allow you to change the data ( I'm guessing not but it's a complete guess), why not just give Excel read only access to the DB?  That way you can know for sure it can't change things.

Comment: It depends on the permissions that the MySQL user that you are using to connect to the database, has...